# Access URL Parameter Variables in Custom ScopedRateThrottle

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Framework and Django REST Framework.

I have an endpoint that needs to be throttled using the `(user, token)` pair, with `user` being the user making the request and `token` being the URL variable specified in the `urls.py`

```
url(r'^api/v2/(?P<token>\w+)/action$', ActionEndpoint.as_view())
```

I have created a custom [*ScopedRateThrottle*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#scopedratethrottle) to accomplish this:

```
class CustomThrottle(ScopedRateThrottle):
    rate = '2/day'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):

        user_id = request.user.pk
        token = (?????????)

        identity = "%s_%s" % (user_id, token)
        cache_key = self.cache_format % {
            'scope': self.scope,
            'ident': identity
        }
        return cache_key
```

**Question:** How should I retrieve the `token` variable from the `request` object in this scenario?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, I personally haven't been in this scenario, so I am not an expert. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `view` object to retrieve parameters from the `url()` pattern:

```
token = view.kwargs['token']
```